# Creating a jQuery like function

Tags: javascript

I'm looking to build a small library of 'oft-used' functions that operate in a similar manner to jQuery, called like so:

```
document.getElementById('my-element').addClass('new-class');
document.getElementsByTagName('section').addClass('another-new-class');
```

OR if I have to:

```
document.getElementById('my-element').LibraryName.addClass('new-class');
etc...
```

I didn't think this would be a difficulty but I can't get my head around this. Basically I'm not sure what I need to do to make this work - my JS is arranged like so:

```
var LibraryName = {

    addClass: function(classname) {

        this.classname += ' ' + classname;

    }

}
```

I tried searching but I'm not sure what I need to search for; every search I do similar to 'jquery like function' (or permutations of) brings back a load of jQuery related stuff! :)

--

I looked at the jQuery source, and while it was very informative there is alot of it, I'd just like this boiled down to the most basic concept if possible.

Comment: There's a user here on SO that has a good blog post about doing this.  Trying to remember who / find it now...

Comment: jQuery doesn't work that way. It calls its methods on a selector, not directly on an element. It wraps the elements, and then returns its own object which can be chained.

Comment: This might be a good read for you: http://blog.buymeasoda.com/creating-a-jquery-like-chaining-api/

Comment: Searching for `javascript method chaining` returns a couple of results. For this going to happen, one has to bind to the prototype of `HTMLElement` but this is not the jQuery way where the elements selected are in an Array-like object that is an instance of jQuery itself.

Comment: [Found it!](http://dfsq.info/site/read/writing-your-own-jquery)  It's by [@dfsq](http://stackoverflow.com/users/949476/dfsq).

Comment: One could add properties to Arrays returned by the [`Sizzle`](http://sizzlejs.com/) selector engine.

Comment: Why use a library for that? `document.getElementById('my-element').classList.add('new-class')`

Comment: @dagg-nabbit Supporting legacy browsers mainly. Basically I want to be able to add, change, remove from a 'library' rather than having to trawl through code looking for out-dated code. I like jQuery but I feel it is too big for my uses on 90% of projects.

Comment: @TonyMerryfield to do what you propose in your example you'd need to modify the prototypes of `Element`/`HTMLElement` and `HTMLCollection`. To do that in a not-horrible way (that won't break `for..in` in other scripts), you'd need `Object.defineProperty`, ruling out pretty much the same legacy browsers that don't support `classList`. jQuery works around this by using its own array-like things, its own selectors, and so on. You can use a standalone function like the answer below, or pollute `HTMLElement` and `HTMLCollection`, or just use `classList` and shim it for old browsers.

Comment: @dagg-nabbit Okay - I'm sensing that this might not be worth the effort :) I actually thought this might be a nice easy Friday morning challenge! I'll use the syntax posted by Frederik Witte - Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function addClass(node, class) {
    if (!node.length) node = [node];
    for (var n = 0, m = node.length; n < m; n++) {
        if ((" " + node[n].className + " ").indexOf(" "+class+" ") >= 0) {
            node.className += " " + class;
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-vs-raw-javascript-2-css3-animation/

Comment: Hi Frederik, this is pretty much what I already have; passing the ID with the new classname - the problem is I'd like to be able to use it with other selectors too.

I'll clarify my question now.

Comment: Ah, woops! Didn't think of this in your post, maybe you should clarify this at the beginning, as you are just using "doc.getElementById"

Comment: Yeah, my bad :) have added additional detail :)

Comment: While this doesn't have the syntax I wanted e.g `document.getElementById('my-element').**addClass('new-class')**;` I think this implementation will suit my needs - thanks.

Comment: But didn't you say you don't want only the 'id' selector, but a universal selector?

Comment: I specifically meant the `addClass(element, class)` versus `element.addClass(class)` - it's fine though, this suits my needs - thanks!